# AWS CDK - Accept Transit Gateway Attachment Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, transit-gateway

I am able to create Transit gateway attachment using the construct CfnTransitGatewayAttachment.

Please let me know if there are any constructs that can be used to accept the attachment request. I have looked at the documentation and could not find anything.

I do know there are few APIs that can be used in boto but want to see if I can complete all the tasks using CDK

Comment: I know that you said that you want to complete the task with CDK and I don't know if you run this in an organization set up but if you do you can change a setting so you automatically accept the request. You will have to use RAM for this.

Comment: @ErikAsplund thank you for the response. yes that is what we are doing right now to overcome this limitation. 

I would still would like to see this construct available in CDK

Comment: Until AWS supports this, if they ever do, you could potentially write a custom Lambda resource to accept the peering attachment request. That would allow you to use CDK.